Generate a Functional Mockup Unit (FMU) embedding a Python interpreter
I want to generate a FMU which embeds a Python script to process inputs and produce outputs. The most straightforward way that I found is to use libraries like unifmu or PythonFMU. However, these solutions require a Python interpreter to be available (with all the required packages) on the target OS, Ubuntu 20.04, where the FMU is executed.
I do not have administrator privileges on the target OS, so I cannot install the Python interpreter that I want and eventually, all the packages that are required.
I wasn't able to find a solution where the Python libraries are embedded in the FMU. Based on the code of PythonFMU, my intuition is that the CMake recipes that generate the FMU should be modified, but I have no idea where to start from.
Is someone aware of possible turnarounds to the problem?
